# Using an event receiver to validate a page

Tags: development, event-receivers, validation

I need to evaluate certain properties of a page whenever it's being saved/published as part of a custom validation I need to implement.

I notice properties has both `Cancel` and `ErrorMessage` properties but as you can guess these aren't really appropriate for validation and showing a message to the user while they can still see the page.

Using an event receiver is preferable but I'm open to other server-side options.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the user will get really unhappy if they spent ages entering content which then disappears if they made a mistake on another field. What is the validation you are doing that means you have to leave the page rather than use normal in page validation?

Comment: But I can still call the base ItemUpdating method by all means and use the beforeProperties/afterProperties to only save the relevant fields. In answer to your question - I need to conditionally mandate certain fields. So, for example, depending on the value of one property - another may be required, may not. Thanks a lot for your reply.